# Create a variable/column using count of events in a 13-week period from start date

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate, posixct

The dataframe consists of case_number (chr), onboarding_date Y-m-d, and raised_at [Y-m-d h:m:s] (POSIXct) for each login event. I'm searching for a way to count how many login events (raised_at) occured between the onboarding date and 13-weeks (or 91 days) after onboarding.

```
log_df <- data.frame(
  case_number = c("000920", "000920", "000920", "000920", "000921", "000921"),
  onboarding_date = as.Date(c("2020-10-27", "2020-10-27", "2020-10-27", "2020-10-27", "2020-11-08", "2020-11-08")),
  raised_at = as.POSIXct(c("2020-10-27 02:52:31", "2020-10-27 05:40:51", "2020-10-27 05:46:25", "2020-10-28 09:05:21", "2020-11-08 23:39:15", "2020-11-11 00:19:16"))
)
```

I believe I need to create an interval object but I'm pretty new at this:

```
int <- interval(ymd("2001-01-01"), ymd("2002-01-01"))
interval = int_shift(int, duration(days = 91))
```

I'm not sure what to do next.

Can I now create a table that will only include raised_at events using onboarding_date+interval to exclude cases outside of my 91 day window of interest?
And then follow that up with a count of raised_at with group_by(case_number)?

I am getting stuck and confusing myself at the next part:

```
log_df %>%
  group_by(case_number) %>%
  mutate(interval = onboarding_date - min(onboarding_date) < 91,
         count_events = sum(raised_at) >= 1,
         event_within_interval = if_else(interval & count_events, 
                                         1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

It doesn't work and I can't seem to make it work.

Error in `mutate()`:

> ! Problem while computing `count_events = sum(raised_at) >= 1`. i The
> error occurred in group 1: case_number = "ACU0000920". Caused by error
> in `Summary.POSIXct()`: ! 'sum' not defined for "POSIXt" objects

I understand that it cannot count the POSIXct dates but I don't know how to fix this error in my code to make it work. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. If you are able to help me see what I am missing, I really appreciate your sage advice for someone just starting out.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the interval in days like this. There's no need to group at this stage, by the look of your data, as the `onboarding_date` appears to be constant by `case_number`. It's quicker not to group.

```r
log_df  <- log_df |>
    mutate(
        interval_days = as.Date(raised_at) - onboarding_date,
        in_window = interval_days > 91
    )

log_df
#   case_number onboarding_date           raised_at interval_days in_window
# 1   1  000920      2020-10-27 2020-10-27 02:52:31        0 days     FALSE
# 2   2  000920      2020-10-27 2020-10-27 05:40:51        0 days     FALSE
# 3   3  000920      2020-10-27 2020-10-27 05:46:25        0 days     FALSE
# 4   4  000920      2020-10-27 2020-10-28 09:05:21        1 days     FALSE
# 5   5  000921      2020-11-08 2020-11-08 23:39:15        0 days     FALSE
# 6   6  000921      2020-11-08 2020-11-11 00:19:16        3 days     FALSE
```

Then to count how many are in each group simply:

```r
log_df |>
    filter(in_window) |>
    group_by(case_number) |>
    summarise(n = n())
```

Your sample data doesn't have any cases where the interval is more than 91 days, but in your real data this should provide what you are asking for. I've used `dplyr` syntax as you're using it here. However, to do something similar in base R, you can do:

```r
# This produces the same data.frame as above
log_df <- within(log_df, {
    interval_days <- as.Date(raised_at) - as.Date(onboarding_date)
    in_window <- interval_days > 91
})

# This produces a named array of counts outside the window for each `case_number` 
with(log_df, tapply(in_window, case_number, sum))

# Alternatively if you want a data.frame
aggregate(in_window ~ case_number, data = log_df, sum)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ran the code and it returned this message: Warning message:
Problem while computing `interval_days = as.Date(raised_at) - onboarding_date`.
i Incompatible methods ("-.Date", "-.POSIXt") for "-" 
> head(log_df)
  case_number onboarding_date           raised_at  interval_days in_window
1  000920      2020-10-27 2020-10-27 02:52:31 -4388917-11-04     FALSE
2  000920      2020-10-27 2020-10-27 05:40:51 -4388917-11-04     FALSE
3  000920      2020-10-27 2020-10-27 05:46:25 -4388917-11-04     FALSE

Comment: Looks like they're both `POSIXct`. Try `interval_days = as.Date(raised_at) - as.Date(onboarding_date)`. If that doesn't work, what is the output of `sapply(log_df, class)`?

Comment: Yes that worked. No errors! Also, your base R code worked perfectly! Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Tiny amendment, just putting it here for the record. Changed > 91 to < 91 because I needed a count of events within the 91 days window. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
log_df %>%
  mutate(events = map_dbl(onboarding_date, ~ sum(between(log_df$raised_at, .x, .x + days(91)))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I ran it and returned this error:
 
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `events = sum(...)`.
Caused by error in `between()`:
! `left` must be length 1
I changed it slightly to:
log_df %>%
  mutate(events = sum(between(log_df$raised_at, min(onboarding_date), min(onboarding_date) + days(91)))) 
 
It ran the code without error except it created a col called events and evey row had 1313 in it. I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: turns out I made a mistake! I created a longer example dataframe to test it out. I was putting the same value in all rows -_- I fixed it now though!

Comment: Thank you. Following this up with a fix helps me understand.